# Editing Excel Template with NPOI C#

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I have an Excel Template which i want to write into with data from a database. Whenever I edit and Save the file in c#,  when I open the template, Microsoft Office Excel says the file is corrupt. Apparently, I think I'm going about editing it wrongly. this is how i went about it below. I am using NPOI 2.0 beta 2. if it matters, the template contains macros and formulas

```
  FIleStream fs = new FileStream(pathString, FIleMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  IWorkbook wkb = WorkbookFactory.Create(fs);

  ISheet sheet = wkb.GetSheet("sheet1");
  ICell cell = sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(column);

  if(cell != null)
  {
      cell.SetCellValue(value);
  }

  FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(pathString, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
  wkb.Write(fs1);

 fs.CLose();
 fs1.Close();
```

But If I try to read the corrupted excel file, i can still retrieve values from the sheet using NPOI. Any pointers as to my errors. Thanks in anticipoation

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Couldn't solve it. I used EPPlus Package instead. But I still use it for reading .XLS files

Comment: I suggest you try NPOI 2.0.6.